# Self-referencing boost variant

Tags: boost

Imagine I have a simple type definition like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double> Value;
```

But, now I want the variant to also hold a vector of itself:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::vector<Value>> Value;
```

This will fail to compile due to **Value** not being known at the time of defining the variant.  Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

```
typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
       int,
       double,
       std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> >::type Value;
```

See the documentation under ["Advanced Topics: Recursive variant types"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.recursive.recursive-variant)

Comment: on re-reading the question I noticed I missed the `vector` there. Adjusted my answer :) Now the example matches _exactly_ the one in the documentation.